# Dictionary passed while iterating dictionary object : Suggestion Needed

Tags: c#

While doing peer code review I observed that my colleague has written a code which loops over a dictionary and has various switch cases, in one of the case he passed the dictionary to get other values. please see the following snippet

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dictionary_Object)
{
    switch (kvp.Key)
    {
    case "Name":
    {
        string ipconnection = GetIPConnectionName(dictionary_Object);
        //Do something with ipconnection
    }
    break;

    case "TCPIPPort":
        //Do something
        break;

    case "TCPIPAddress":
        //Do something
        break;

    case "DefaultProViewNXGAddress":
        //Do something
        break;

    // Setting values of the Timeout parameters
    case "Comms_TimeOut":
    case "Comms_Retries":
    case "FW_File_Retries":
        Another_Dictionary[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to improvise this.

Comment: what is the problem with that code ? You can start by improving the identation.

Comment: This question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: probably you need to use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is there a better way? Who's to say? Give 10 devs the same challenge, and there will be 10 different implementations. As far as passing the entire dictionary_Object instead of just the current KeyValuePair, that's probably not necessary and probably not very "performant," but you'd have to show GetIPConnectionName() to know for sure what's going on with that.

Comment: @OrelEraki The question does not belong on Code Review, at least not in its current form. It lacks an explanation of what the code is trying to accomplish, and the `//Do something` placeholders need to be filled in, else the question will be closed as hypothetical code.

Comment: Its pretty simple pre-filter the dictionaries based on there name and then execute the code on the proper dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than iterate over the entire dictionary and then filter by a `switch` I'd be inclined to define an extension method to selectively execute some code based on a given key. After all, the key can only be found once.

Here's the extension method:

```
public static bool IfContainsKeyThenExecute<K, V>(
    this Dictionary<K, V> dictionary, K key, Action<K, V> action)
{
    V value;
    var found = dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    if (found)
    {
        action(key, value);
    }
    return found;
}
```

Then the code looks like this:

```
dictionary_Object.IfContainsKeyThenExecute("Name", (k, v) =>
{
    string ipconnection = GetIPConnectionName(dictionary_Object);
    //Do something with ipconnection
});

dictionary_Object.IfContainsKeyThenExecute("TCPIPPort", (k, v) => { /* Do Something */ });
dictionary_Object.IfContainsKeyThenExecute("TCPIPAddress", (k, v) => { /* Do Something */ });
dictionary_Object.IfContainsKeyThenExecute("DefaultProViewNXGAddress", (k, v) => { /* Do Something */ });

dictionary_Object.IfContainsKeyThenExecute("Comms_TimeOut", (k, v) => Another_Dictionary[k] = v);
dictionary_Object.IfContainsKeyThenExecute("Comms_Retries", (k, v) => Another_Dictionary[k] = v);
dictionary_Object.IfContainsKeyThenExecute("FW_File_Retries", (k, v) => Another_Dictionary[k] = v);
```

Comment: I am not able to up vote your answer, because of number of points in reputation. :(

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple pre-filter the dictionaries based on there name and then execute the code on the proper dictionary

```
var nameDict = dictionary_Object.Where(x => x.Key == "name").ToDictionary(k => k.Key);

//do your operations on the filtered dictionary etc...
string ipconnection = GetIPConnectionName(nameDict);
```